# WiFi connection

Tags: 14.04

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an old dell laptop to replace a slow windows XP operating system but can't get the WiFi to work. The internet works with an ethernet cable but no WiFi any idea's

Comment: Please edit your answer with the output of "lshw -C network"

Comment: Haven't got a clue what that means

Comment: In terminal, type the command: "sudo lshw -C network". Copy and paste the results into the question.

Comment: Ok where do I find terminal sorry I'm quite new to this

Comment: Press the Windows button, the Dash will appear, then type terminal and open the program showing on the list. Type the given command and press enter.

Comment: Click the circly thing at the top left, or Unity "Dash"- it looks similar to the Windows start button. Type Terminal. When the Terminal icon shows up, click it. Type the command "sudo lshw -C network". Enter your User Password. Click and drag across the text, and use the key combo Ctrl+Shift+C to copy the text, or right click on the terminal and click copy. Navigate to this question, and paste.

Comment: Right managed to get terminal and enter the command it's asking for the password but it's not typing anything

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install proprietary drivers.

You can find the driver settings here:

- Open up the ‘Software & Updates’ tool from the Unity Dash
- Click the ‘Additional Drivers’ tab

Check if your wifi adapter is listed there.